# Check if a Binary Tree is Balanced in Scala

Tags: scala, binary-tree

I defined a binary Tree structure using case classes and trait in Scala. I have done it like this:

```
sealed trait Tree[+T]

case class Node[A](v: A, l: Tree[A], r: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
case class Leaf[A](v: A) extends Tree[A]
case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]
```

If given a Tree instance, I want to check if the instance is balanced where the definition of balance is number of right elements equals number of elements to the left.

I have tried the following method (using the accumulator pattern) to get what I want:

```
sealed trait Tree[+T]

case class Node[A](v: A, l: Tree[A], r: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
case class Leaf[A](v: A) extends Tree[A]
case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]

def isBalanced[A](tree: Tree[A]) = {
  def inner(tree: Tree[A], acc: (Int, Int)): Boolean = tree match {
    case n: Node[A] => inner(n.l, (acc._1 + 1, acc._2)) && inner(n.r, (acc._1, acc._2 + 1))
    case l: Leaf[A] => inner(tree, acc)
    case Empty      => acc._1 == acc._2 
  }

  inner(tree, (0, 0)) 
}

val node: Node[Int] = Node(1, Node(2, Leaf(3), Leaf(4)), Node(5, Leaf(6), Leaf(7)))
isBalanced[Int](node)
```

This runs into a indefinite loop and I'm pretty sure that I made some stupid mistake with my logic. I'm not assertive about where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Your bug is in `case Leaf`: it should be calling `inner(Empty, acc)`. The way you have it, it just keeps calling itself - thus the infinite loop.

This would fix the infinite loop, but the implementation is still wrong: basically, you keep descending the left branch, incrementing the left `acc`, until you hit the leaf. Then you compare left and right (which is still zero), and return. This implementation will always return false, except for a tree, that is just a single leaf node.

Also, your definition of balanced tree is wrong.
For example, something like this:

```
                     A
                    / \
                   B   E
                  /   / \
                 C   F  G
                /
               D
```

Matches the definition (there are three elements on left and right), but is not really balanced.
On the other hand, something like this:

```
                    A
                   / 
                  B
```

Does not match the definition, but is actually balanced.

The correct definition of the balanced tree is one, in which both left and right subtrees are balanced, *and* their heights differ by at most one.

With that in mind, we can write a correct implementation as something like this (it returns the height of the tree if it is balanced, -1 otherwise):

```
   def balanced(root: Tree[_]): Int = root match {
      case Empty => 0
      case Leaf(_) => 1
      case Node(_, left, right) => 
        val l = balanced(left)
        val r = balanced(right)
        if (l < 0 || r < 0 || abs(l - r) > 1) -1 else (l max r) + 1
    }
```